# Moving folders within Microsoft OneDrive painfully slow

Tags: windows-11, onedrive

On a Windows 11 64-bit laptop with 16GB RAM / 11th-gen Core i7 CPU.

Cutting a folder and pasting it into a new destination, the Windows Explorer move dialogue opens and sits at 0% for about 3 minutes.

Is there any way to improve this slow speed?

Once the move starts, the transfer says it is going to take 12 hours to move a folder of 725 MB, speed of 1.23KB/s.

The laptop has an SSD.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Is the new destination found on the same computer?

Comment: Yes, it is just a few folders away @harrymc

Comment: This is very abnormal. Check the SMART status of the disk, and run chkdsk. Look in the Event Viewer for any error/warning notification regarding the disk. I would suggest to ensure you have backups for data on this disk.

Comment: How many files? How long did the process actually take once it got going? If it took a long time with a lot of files to make its first assessment, that assessment would probably rapidly come down after a few recalculations.

Comment: Could you also explain what's the connection with OneDrive.

Comment: @harrymc I am cutting a folder within OneDrive using File Explorer and pasting it into another folder a few levels away. SMART status = OK. No errors in Event Viewer > Hardware Events. Chkdsk fine. The move is still extremely slow, about 1 file every 0.75 seconds. 42,920 Files, 5,595 Folders. The assessment is now 17 hours.

Comment: @Tetsujin I intermittently receive an error: "An unexpected error is keeping you from copying the file. If you continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search for help with this probem. Error 0x800701AA: The cloud operation was not commpleted before the time-out period expired". The move is still extremely slow, about 1 file every 0.75 seconds.

Comment: It sounds like it's having to check & confirm with OneDrive for every individual move, unlike a local-only move which would just be negotiated between the OS & disk drivers. Also sounds like you're swamping your connection. Try Ethernet if you're on wifi, or if you can't, google 'bufferbloat' & see https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/

Comment: @Tetsujin, is there any way to a local-only move with OneDrive? Can't see how on Google. I get a BUFFERBLOAT GRADE of B. I'm on Ethernet already.

Comment: I don't really know quite how OneDrive handles its comms for something like this, tbh. It's one of those things I tried for a couple of days, didn't like & haven't looked at since. I'm generally not a fan of this type of online 'lose all your files in one fell swoop if you make a mistake' structures - DropBox, iCloud etc.

Comment: Hmm, what mistake could make cloud backups lose all files? My mistake, or their mistake? What alternative do you use? @Tetsujin

Comment: These are not backup structures primarily, they're synchronisation structures at heart. Delete a file from one computer, watch it vanish from all your others. Seen it happen to too many people. I handle sync & backup in two distinct sets of actions. [I'm old, I come from a time when backups were entirely the user's prerogative… & fault if they went wrong. ;))

Comment: I've contacted OneDrive support. They'll probably blame Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed within the post
[Moving or Copying Files: Painfully Slow, Loss of Data](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/moving-or-copying-files-painfully-slow-loss-of-data/m-p/238315/).

Here are some excerpts :

> We abandoned the "move" proces. With moving from one Sharepoint group to another (or from Onedrive to Sharepoint), it moves all history files, and it takes forever. Fastest way for us was to first sync all files on file explorer (always keep on this device option), copy them on new Sharepoint group, and then delete files from old location.

And also :

> I'm using OneDrive client sync, moving folder by folder and it is taking days. Each folder I move (about 5,000 files, 600 MB) takes many hours to sync with OneDrive client status stalled as "Moving sync files". I have another folder with 200,000 files to move, I will try sync with OneDrive Client, always keep on this device and then, use the migration tool to upload it to the new SP library.

It seems like the fastest method is copying the files to your
computer, creating the new OneDrive folders, copying the files
to their new place from the computer, finally deleting the old
folders.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me today

Answer (score 1):

No real answer here except OneDrive is generally painfully slow with lots of files. It has recently implemented the concept of moving files so when you cut & paste on the same tenant, it *should* move the files faster. I've left OneDrive moving about 10,000 files now for about 10 hours...

[image]

When migrating data on SharePoint or OneDrive, I tend to use robocopy to make a complete copy and then on go live day, refresh the copy and then delete the original once it's finished resynchronising. The download/upload is of course very slow but you can seed it.

It just feels safer than relying on OneDrive move.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to move 11GB of data to a new computer at work, and totally gave up on OneDrive as it proved to be extremely slow.

The best option for me was to use http://wetransfer.com and pack the data into 2GB chunks (when using the free account).

Worked much faster.